# How to trigger SelectIndexChanged event to VListBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi, listbox, custom-controls

Somebody know the [VListBox](http://www.vbaccelerator.com/home/NET/Code/Controls/ListBox_and_ComboBox/VListBox/article.asp)?
It is fast to load item to the listbox.

But I can't get the SelectIndexChanged Event be triggered by set SelectIndex.
Somebody know how to trigger that event by winapi or something else?
VlistBox source code is in the page above.

Answer (score 0):

does the event get fired when you click on the item with a mouse?

if so then it may be by design.  also if you are selecting it via code then a better way is not "how to manually trigger the event".  consider refactoring the event handling code into a new **DoSelectionChanged**() method and have the code that calls SelectIndex() call that.  in this way the "meaty" stuff that normally would be in an event callback can be used by other methods, not just the callback.

hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Wy don't you call the EventHandler manually?

```
vListBox1_selectedIndexChanged(null,null);
```